# How to scroll to next section of page when Bootstrap carousel scrolled to it's last child horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

HTML

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <h1>lorem</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
           <h1>lorem</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <h1>lorem</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="item0 active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1" class="item1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2" class="item2"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#slider').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
        $(this).carousel('prev');
    }
    else if ($("#slider .carousel-inner .carousel-item:last").hasClass("active")) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    else{
        $(this).carousel('next');
    }
});
```

Here, the mouseweel event listener is moving the Bootstrap carousel to the next slider. How to scroll the page to the next section when the carousel reached it's last slide. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi you can enable loop in bootstrap carousal slider;

Comment: @Raj as my suggestion you should not use the bootstrap slider as its already deprecated either you can use owlcarousel2 and I m defiantly sure it would be good experience with owl slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `e.stopPropagation();` you should use `$('#slider').off('mousewheel');`. However, there are couple of things to note here as well:

- First off, `.bind()` has been deprecated as of jQuery 3.0, thus you should not use it any more. Use `.on()` instead to bind event listeners.
- Second, the `mousewheel` event has the delta value available as it's second argument. So instead of using `e.originalEvent.wheelDelta` you could simply use that.
- The `.carousel-inner` part in the css selector of the `else if` is  unnecessary, as `#slider .carousel-item` already targets the required elements.
- FYI: The `wheelDelta / 120` division is completely useless in this situation as you compare the result to zero.

So your script could look something like this:

```
$('#slider').on('mousewheel', function(e, delta) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (delta > 0) {
        $(this).carousel('prev');
    }
    else if ($("#slider .carousel-item:last").hasClass("active")) {
        // e.stopPropagation();
        $('#slider').off('mousewheel');
    }
    else {
        $(this).carousel('next');
    }
});
```

Working snippet ahead:

```js
$('#slider').on('mousewheel', function(e, delta) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (delta > 0) {
        $(this).carousel('prev');
    }
    else if ($("#slider .carousel-item:last").hasClass("active")) {
        // e.stopPropagation();
        $('#slider').off('mousewheel');
    }
    else {
        $(this).carousel('next');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 200vh;
    background-color: #E6E6FA !important;
}

#slider {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <h1>lorem</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
           <h1>lorem</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <h1>lorem</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="item0 active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1" class="item1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2" class="item2"></li>
    </ul>
</div>



<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: great.Thank you so much.

Comment: I have set $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
}); but on mousewheel it is moving to last child without targeting second slider item.